# How to install winexe on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows, software-installation, remote-access, remote

I don't seem to find a working tutorial on how to install [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/), which is a program that allows for execution of commands on a Windows machine remotely from a Linux machine. None of the tutorials I've followed so far has worked on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the read me:

> Here you can find source files(tar.gz).
>   *Precompiled packages for different systems and repositories are available at "Build Service":http://build.opensuse.org/project/repositories?project=home:ahajda:winexe*.

This gets me to:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ahajda:/winexe/xUbuntu_12.10/i386/
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ahajda:/winexe/xUbuntu_12.04/
```

and a debian installer for 12.10 and 12.04. Looks to me you can install it with Ubuntu software center:

[image]

and

[image]

I do not see a problem installing it (nor the need ;) ):

```
winexe
winexe version 1.00
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPLv3
Usage: winexe [-?] [-?] [-?] [-?NP] [-?NPV] [-?|--help] [--usage] [-d|--debuglevel DEBUGLEVEL]
    [--debug-stderr] [-s|--configfile CONFIGFILE] [--option=name=value]
    [-l|--log-basename LOGFILEBASE] [--leak-report] [--leak-report-full]
    [-R|--name-resolve NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER]
    [-O|--socket-options SOCKETOPTIONS] [-n|--netbiosname NETBIOSNAME]
    [-S|--signing on|off|required] [-W|--workgroup WORKGROUP]
    [--realm=REALM] [-i|--scope SCOPE] [-m|--maxprotocol MAXPROTOCOL]
    [-U|--user [DOMAIN/]USERNAME[%PASSWORD]] [-N|--no-pass]
    [--password=STRING] [-A|--authentication-file FILE] [-P|--machine-pass]
    [--simple-bind-dn=STRING] [-k|--kerberos STRING] [-V|--version]
    [--uninstall] [--reinstall] [--system]
    [--runas=[DOMAIN\]USERNAME%PASSWORD] [--runas-file=FILE]
    [--interactive=0|1] [--ostype=0|1|2] //host command
```

Comment: The need is that my Ubuntu is the backup center for my Windows and my Mac and when Ubuntu has finished backing up files from Windows and Mac (via mounted cifs/samba folders) it may need to execute some commands remotely. No problems with Mac, my backup script can simply SSH into it from Ubuntu, but if you want Windows to shutdown or hibernate automatically after backup is complete (nightly backup) there are no other ways other than installing winexe on Ubuntu or SSH on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, but when I search for `winexe` in my Ubuntu Software Center (12.04) I see `No items match "winexe"`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Also it's much more appreciated if you tell us the commands that we should execute to install `winexe`. Thank you again.

Comment: No, just download the deb! Then click it and let software center handle it. No commands needed ;)

Answer (score 4):

Rinzwind's answer now contains dead links, and I think he dismissed your request for a command line solution far too quickly.  For advantages of command line over GUI, see http://www.aswedeingermany.de/50SoftwareDevelopment/50ShellVsGUI.html.

To install winexe on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin 64bit (or others):

1. Go to 
   software.opensuse.org/package/winexe
   ..and find the link for your system.
2. Use these commands to download the link for your system and install it (example for Precise Pangolin 12.04, 64bit):

   ```
   wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/uibmz:/opsi:/opsi40-testing/xUbuntu_12.04/amd64/winexe_1.00.1-1_amd64.deb

   sudo dpkg --install winexe_1.00.1-1_amd64.deb
   ```

Done.

Comment: The download link for winexe for Ubuntu 12.04 in Rinzwind's answer ( `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ahajda:/winexe/xUbuntu_12.04/` ) is alive. The download link for winexe for Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't matter because Ubuntu 12.10 is End of Life.

Comment: Since winexec doesn't seem to have been updated in a while this answer seems like the best solution, and it is command-line :) I used this without modification for `Ubuntu 14.04` as there isn't a newer package than what is listed at this time.